# VSTS Adding input parameters to release or environment deployment

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, release-management

Is there a way to add inputs to a release or environment deployment, each time a new release gets triggered?

For example, I would want a parameter when launching a release or environment deployment that could be used inside of a step. Is this possible to accomplish through a step or some other way?

Comment: Not so clearly about your issue. Do you want to add an additional parameter when launching a release or just want to change variable value when launching a release?

Comment: You can mark variables to be changed before queuing, but I would like to understand your scenario. Can you elaborate the question a little?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, I wanted something similar a while back.
I did manage to do it, by putting a file with the parameter in the artifact, so I basically fixed it in the build

Comment: Bizarre, I'm confused why that wouldn't be available in a release management tool.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but in case anybody else comes across it, this is possible by creating a Draft Release.  It's not very intuitive like Build variables are but it is possible...

1. Create a Draft Release from the release definition.
2. Change the variable values in the Draft Release & save.
3. Start the release from the Draft Release.

Found the solution here:
[Defining variables while creating a Release in VSTS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/05/18/defining-variables-while-creating-a-release-in-rm-a-k-a-draft-releases/)